# Where is the godef binary?

Tags: go

I am trying to use godef from emacs on OpenSUSE.

Tried to install godef with:
`go get code.google.com/p/rog-go/exp/cmd/godef`

Also tried: `go install code.google.com/p/rog-go/exp/cmd/godef`

My `$GOROOT/bin` folder has `{go, godoc, gofmt}` files, but no godef.
There are godef source files in `$GOPATH/src/code.google.com/p/rog-go/exp/cmd/godef`

Where and how do I get the godef executable?

Comment: It is a good idea to always use proper grammar and punctuation, as well as code tags. This makes it easier for other to read your question, and give their answers. Good job of using examples of where you have already looked though :)

Comment: `get` and `install` bit binaries in `$GOPATH/bin`.

Comment: @JimB, How do I install the binaries in `$GOPATH/bin`? I already tried go get and go install. I did not find any relevant packages with zypper to install either.

Comment: You just did. (my comment should say they "*put* binaries in"). Are they there?

Comment: @JimB. Got it! Thanks. I don't know why my locate command did not find it in `$GOPATH/bin`. I just had to add `$GOPATH/bin` to `$PATH`.

Comment: @NeoWerk Could you please answer your own question and approve it :)

Answer (score 3):

After running `go install some.package`, the binary will be placed in `$GOPATH/bin`

Answer (score 3):

`go get github.com/rogpeppe/godef` should install it for you.